# CallBack API ВК На python

Tags: vkontakte-api, callback, python-3.7

Как к боту вк на python подключить callback api. 
Например чтобы, если человек отписался от группы, то бот ему что-то напишет. 
Как такое реализовать на python?

Comment: В чём конкретно у Вас проблема? Не знаете библиотеку? Не знаете, как получить событие? Что?

Comment: Не знаю как получить событие

Comment: Мне бы знать как подключить callback api vk к  python файлу, и получать события

Comment: Callback API подключается к Вашему веб-серверу. То бишь для этого на Вашем веб-сервере должен быть соответствующий бекенд для получения и обработки событий от Callback API. Думаю, вам, скорее, нужен LongPoll API.